# How do I properly initialize a set in Python?

Tags: python, set, initialization, cs50

I initially defined a set using `destinations={"x",}`. Then I tried to remove something using `destinations=destinations.discard("x")`. However, the terminal says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'discard'` when I try to run it. It seems that it is not yet a set. I included a comma with the braces when initializing it and at least it should be a string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean: `destinations.discard("x")`? You must have had `destinations=destinations.discard(sth)` prior to getting the error. Don't do that. `discard()` returns `None`.  Also you meant to write: `destinations = {"x"}`

Comment: @quamrana `{"x",}` is fine; trailing commas are optionally allowed in most sequence-like contexts, such as set displays, list displays, and function-call argument lists . (Tuple displays as well, though in the case of `(1,)`, it is *required*, as it's the only thing distinguishing a single-element tuple display from an ordinary parenthesized expression.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quamrana's comment answers the essence of your question, but to break it down:

```
destinations={"x","y",}   #"y" added for the sake of demonstration
destinations = destinations.discard("x")
print(destinations)       # Output = '' i.e. no output
```

If you see `type(destinations)`, it will output as `<class 'NoneType'>`

That's because discard (similar to many other methods) returns a NoneType object.
*(The same is true for other methods like list.append(). However, note that is this not true for all methods. For example dict.pop(key) returns a non-NoneType Object.)*

Now for the proper way to do it:

```
destinations={"x","y",}   #"y" added for the sake of demonstration
destinations.discard("x")
print(destinations)       # Output: {'y'}
```

If you see `type(destinations)`, it will output as `<class 'set'>`

Interestingly, if you were to reassign the variable, your original set would still be affected.

```
destinations = {"x","y"}
new_set = destinations
new_set.discard('x')
print(new_set)         # output = {'y'}
print(destinations)    # output = {'y'}
```

Since you're learning CS50, i think David will cover this at some point when teaching lists! Have fun learning :)